# pass boolean data between Android applications

Tags: android

I need to pass boolean data between Android applications, is there any simple method other than Sharedpreference or contentproviders. Please help me to find a solution !

Comment: Why don't you like ContentProvider? It's the best way to do that

Comment: You can also use file to store boolean value. Other than those, I'm not sure there is other way.

Comment: need to pass a single boolean data between applications. package names of both app are known to me. for me content provider is bit confusing !

Comment: use public static boolean isCheck true or false ; and in other class let say A.isCheck and use. may be it help you

Comment: where should i define this 'public static boolean' method or variable, in APP1 or APP2 ? and need to use value of boolean variable as a mutex variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Explaining the code. 

// Start as a main entry point, does not expect to receive data.
Intent it=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN); 
// Return PackageManager instance to find global package information.
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager(); 
// Specifies the application to be called
it = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.your.app.packagename"); 
it.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
// "key" is a parameter name, "value" is a true or false
params.putBoolean(key, value); 
it.putExtras(params); 
int requestCode = 0; // passing reuest code = 0
// Starts a main activity from specific package
startActivityForResult(it,requestCode);

// I hope that this topic be useful
```

Comment: Can you explain your code? Code-only answers are candidates for deletion as they don't help others learn as much as well-commented or explained code.

Comment: Aha. You can [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29905429/edit) your answer to do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With the use of Intent

you can pass boolean value from one application to another.

Comment: can you please provide some samples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a socket connection between the apps. [Here is a tutorial](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/).

Answer (score 0):

Use intents

intent.putExtras("value", true);

Boolean value= getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("value");

Comment: need to pass data between two different applications also navigation between app activity while changing boolean value is undesirable for my application !

Comment: Use implicit intents as you are choosing an contact from any application using picker intent.